# Type of `values` in class `KeyValueTensorInitializer` of TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I was wondering if a list of `Tensor` could be the `values` in class `KeyValueTensorInitializer` of TensorFlow to construct a `HashTable`?